# Download HTTPS resources like CSS/Images/etc. of a page using JavaScript and writing them to a temp file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome that converts a given webpage to a PDF. To do this, I download the outerHTML of the document and pass it to a software which further converts the HTML to a PDF file. The problem is that the software doesn't have access to data of type https://* so that if an external style sheet is used in the document, it will not show up in the PDF because the software was never able to download it. To overcome this problem, I want to download the HTTPS data at JavaScript level and write it to a temp file, and append the outerHTML, that we'll send to the software, with (HTTPS data, temp file) pair tags so that whenever an HTTPS source is encountered in the outerHTML by the software, it will simply find the corresponding temp file and download the data from there. I want to understand how the HTTPS resources can be downloaded and saved in a temp file at JavaScript level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! It can be done my making a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest and using a WebKitBlobBuilder. However, I'm still struck at one point: How do I save the image to a local temporary file using JavaScript from the WebKitBlobBuilder object? I'm able to create a url using Chrome.extension.getURL, but the link only opens up in Google Chrome. Any help will be appreciated.